# Resetting Value in Before Update still getting written to the Object history

Tags: apex

I have a before update trigger that prevents an integration user from updating a particular field (whilst allowing it to continue with its updates of other fields), by simply setting it to the original value in Trigger.oldmap.

According to the docs:

> Field history is not recorded until the end of a trigger. If you
>   query field history in a trigger, you will not see any history for the
>   current transaction.

However, I am getting two logs in the history object showing the integration user setting it and then the trigger setting it back. Any ideas how to resolve??

Clearly, changing the integration so that it no longer tries to update that field is an option, but for several reasons that's more challenging than it should be, and I'm not sure why my original approach wouldn't work.!

```
if(UserInfo.getLastName() == 'Integration'){
        for(LIM_Account__c newAccount : newCAMap.values())
        {
            if(newAccount.Account_Name__c != oldCAMap.get(newAccount.id).Account_Name__c && newAccount.Record_Type_Text__c == 'Account')
            {
                newAccount.Account_Name__c = oldCAMap.get(newAccount.id).Account_Name__c;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code if you want help!

Comment: There's nothing contradictory about your observation. The quote is simply saying that the history objects are not committed to the database until the end of the trigger-- not that they wouldn't be logged at all.

Comment: Interesting... so the implication is that there is no way to avoid the change getting logged (other than changing the integration)??